# counting battleships on given board

Tags: python

I'm getting input of board NxM which looks like a board of battleship game. "#" represents battleship and "-" represents empty space. Ships are not placed one next to each other and not diagonally. (must be "-" between two ships). 
I need to count how much ships are on the board.

I know how to count when the ship is size 1x1.

```
subnum=0

for i in range(len(board[1:-2])):
    for j in range(len(board[1:-2])):
        if board[i][j] == "#":
            if board[i+1][j] == "-" and board[i-1][j]=="-" and board[i][j+1]=="-" and board[i][j-1]=="-":

            subnum += 1
```

Comment: What is the size of your ship now? And are they placed vertically?

Comment: Are diagonally placed ships allowed?

Comment: The size of the ship is unknown and can be any size. The ships can not be placed diagonally, and not one close to other (without "-" between), and not one covering other.

Comment: You have the right idea, but currently for a ship bigger than 1 you won't count it at all.  You do want to count those if this is the first # you have hit for it.  So, instead of testing all 4 next-door squares just check the 2 squares "before" the one you are on.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If ships are not horizontically and not next to each other you could just use your code, but only test if the field above a "#" is "-" (or nothing, if the ship touches the border of the board) and count that.

```
 --#------
 --#--#---
 --#--#---
 -----#---
```

In this example, it would count 2, because only 2 '#' have no other "#" above them. In your example I also don't really get your for loops (they are both the same, but you write the board is NxM). I would suggest something like this:

```
 subnum=0

 for x in range(len(board)):
     for y in range(len(board[x])):
         if board[x][y] == "#" and (y == 0 or board[x][y-1] == "-"):
              subnum += 1
```

I used x, y here to clearify how "board" looks like (x -> horizontal, y -> vertical). Maybe you need to change that, if the "board" looks different.

This code will work for all kind of ships placed horizontally and vertically:

```
 def check(board):
     visited = set()
     subnum = 0

     for x in range(len(board)):
         for y in range(len(board[x])):
             if not (x,y) in visited: #we havn't looked at this field already
                 if board[x][y] == '#': #a ship!
                     subnum += 1
                     if x < len(board) - 1: #need to test if ship expands to the right
                         for x1 in range(x+1, len(board)):
                             if board[x1][y] == '#':
                                 visited.add((x1,y)) #avoid this field later, because it belongs to the already counted ship
                             else:
                                 break #end of ship reached

                     if y < len(board[x]) - 1: #need to test if ship expands to the bottom
                         for y1 in range(y+1, len(board[x])):
                             if board[x][y1] == '#':
                                 visited.add((x,y1)) #avoid this field later, because it belongs to the already counted ship
                             else:
                                 break #end of ship reached


     return subnum
```

Okay, the third approch, without set, even easier:

```
 def check2(board):
     subnum = 0

     for x in range(len(board)):
         for y in range(len(board[x])):
             if board[x][y] == '#': #a ship!
                 if (x == 0 or board[x-1][y] != '#') and (y == 0 or board[x][y-1] != '#'):
                     subnum += 1

 return subnum
```

gives:

```
>>> board = [ '#-#-#######-###---#' ]
>>> check2(board)
5

>>> board = [ '#-#-#######-###---#', '#---------------#-#' ]
>>> check2( board )
6
```

Comment: The second line basically runs only on the top right side of the board, isn't it? for example- when horizontally x=2, vertically it will run only 2 lines down the board.

Comment: I assumed the board is basically a list of columns. So the first loop runs through the columns (x) and the second loop runs through the lines (y). So you iterate over every possible coordinate of the board. So in your example, if x = 2, the second loop will run through the complete third column.

Comment: If my board looks like that
# # - #
it will count 3 ships instead of 2.
And if the board larger it will count less than there actually are.
The board can be any size.

Comment: Yes. You described "ships are not paced next to each other and not horizontally". If that is correct, the board "##-#" would be incorrect. As I wrote, the algorithm only works under that assumption. If ships can be placed horizontally and vertically, the algorithm will be more complicated.

Comment: I've added a version that works for horizontally and vertically placed ships. As I wrote, it's much more complex than the other one.

Comment: Yeh sorry, I meant diagonally, I fixed it. Yet, I'm not sure why but your code doesn't count all the ships, although it looks correct. And is there a why to do it without the set()?

Comment: I couldn't find an example where not all ships were count. - Without the set? I think it would be possible, but again it would be more complex. Why would you prefer that?

Comment: for example:

# - # - # # # # # # # - # # # - - - #

the code will count 13 insted of 5 (I think it's counting "#" and the size of the ship can be larger than only one "#"). And without set because it's part of an assignment in the university and I'm not allowed to use it.

Comment: The first one counts 13 (as expected), the second one I added later counts 5, because it can deal with horizonal and vertical ships. I don't know what you're trying, but "check(['#-#-#######-###---#'])" returns 5. I don't know how to help you any further, though. It's kind of fun to solve such problems, but I don't know what your constraints are. If you can't use a set, what can you use? A list? No collection at all?

Comment: I've added a third approach, that doesn't use anything like set/list. However, I added no comments there. You have to understand for yourself how that works. I was teaching at university and you really should try hard to solve these problems yourself, otherwise you will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler version based on the idea in my comment above.

```
def check(board):
    subnum = 0

    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board[i])):
            if (
                board[i][j] == "#"
                and (i == 0 or board[i-1][j] == "-")
                and (j == 0 or board[i][j-1] == "-")
            ):
                subnum += 1
    return subnum
```

Answer (score -2):

```
from numpy import *
from array import * #imports
board=array([#,-,-,-][-,-,#,-][#,-,-,-][-,-,-,#]) #your board data
array('u',board.flatten()).count('#') #display count of bartterships
```

Comment: please forgive the data and set them as you needed

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Include an explanation what your code does and how (and why) it solves the problem of the question.

Comment: That will count the '#' characters, not the ships. One ship may be composed by more '#'

Comment: sorry for the wrong character, here in my code i wrote logic that he/she can use by own and for explanation i added comment to code.